# library (ng2-auto-complete) which declares Ng2AutoCompleteModule has not processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Tags: angular, autocomplete, ivy

I am working on upgrading angular(2-15) and getting below error, Could someone please help?

This likely means that the library (ng2-auto-complete) which declares Ng2AutoCompleteModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is
expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I have tried disabling IVY but I was getting renderer was not supported error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced incompatible issue with angular Ivy for autocomplete module which I was using. I replaced it with angular-ng-autocomplete 2.0.12. After modifying to this package in package.json. AutocompleteLibModule needs to be imported to app.module.ts and changes need to be done in HTML pages where autocomplete being used.